# Does the series solution to $2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-8x y=0$ have an infinite radius of convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

If the differential equation does not have any singular points, does it mean it has an infinite radius of convergence? Is there a theorem for this?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Airy equation?

Comment: The question in the title differs from the one in the body. This is quite misleading since one doesn't know which of them to answer. Concerning the question in the body: no, this is false; look at $y'=y^2$, which has solutions with singularities.

Answer (score 0):

To solve
$$
y''=4xy
$$
let
$$
y=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k
$$
Then
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty k(k-1)a_kx^{k-2}=4\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^{k+1}
$$
This means,
$$
(k+3)(k+2)a_{k+3}=4a_k
$$
By the ratio test
$$
\limsup_{k\to\infty}\frac4{(k+3)(k+2)}=0
$$
Thus, the series has an infinite radius of convergence.